# JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, outofmemoryerror, sourcemap

Имеется конфиг для webpack:

```
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const path = require("path");

module.exports = () => ({
    devtool: "nosources-source-map",
    output: {
        sourceMapFilename: "themes/[name]/js/source_map.map",
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(svg|ttf|woff|woff2|eot|jpe?g|png|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "file-loader",
                        options: {
                            name: '[path][name].[ext]'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(path.resolve(__dirname, '../static/build'), {allowExternal: true}),
        new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({cssProcessorOptions: {discardComments: {removeAll: true}}}),
        new UglifyJsPlugin({sourceMap: true})
    ],

    performance: {
        hints: false
    }
});
```

После запуска проходить n времени и вылетает ошибка:

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node::DecodeWrite
 2: node_module_register
 3: v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory
 4: v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory
 5: v8::internal::Factory::NewFixedArray
 6: v8::internal::HashTable<v8::internal::SeededNumberDictionary,v8::internal::SeededNumberDictionaryShape>::NewInternal
 7: v8::internal::HashTable<v8::internal::SeededNumberDictionary,v8::internal::SeededNumberDictionaryShape>::EnsureCapacity
 8: v8::internal::Dictionary<v8::internal::SeededNumberDictionary,v8::internal::SeededNumberDictionaryShape>::Add
 9: v8::internal::WasmDebugInfo::SetupForTesting
10: v8::internal::WasmDebugInfo::SetupForTesting
11: v8::internal::SharedFunctionInfo::SetScript
12: v8::internal::JSReceiver::class_name
13: v8::internal::SourcePositionTableIterator::Advance
14: v8::internal::SourcePositionTableIterator::Advance
15: 0000015449A843C1
```

Как можно пофиксить?

P.s. в `devtool` обязательно должно быть `nosources-source-map`

Comment: Файл подкачки увеличьте...

Comment: если так `webpack --max-memory 12288`, то не помогло

Comment: @AlexeyPresman, это не относится к `webpack`, `webpack` использует средства node, V8 постоянно контролирует выделение памяти в куче и по стандарту максимальный объем это 512мб, попробуйте `node --max_old_space_size=2048 ./node_modules/.bin/webpack`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо за ответы Pavel Mayorov и overthesanity.
Для увеличения лимита памяти webpack нужно было добавить `NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192` в файле `package.json`.